# SSH access to Github: shell okay, Jenkins fails

Tags: authentication, github, jenkins

*Before you instantly mark this as a possible duplicate please read the entire text*

TLDR:
I'm trying to set up a jenkins to read a **private** Github repository. When I use jenkins credentials with `username/password` it works, when I use jenkins credentials with a `private key` it does not and I'm getting an "invalid username / or password" error.

Full description:

1. I have a jenkins 2.5 installed on apache-tomcat 8, jenkins is running under the user `tomcat8`. Credential plugin (2.1.4), Git client plugin (1.19.6), Gitplugin (2.5.2), Github API Plugin (1.76), GitHub plugin (1.19.2), SSH credential plugin (1.12) are also installed. Git is running in version 2.1.4
2. I've created an ssh-keypair **with empty password** for the user tomcat8 [logged in as tomcat8 via `sudo -su tomcat8`]
3. I've added the public key to the private Github repository
4. I've created a jenkins credentials `ssh username with private key` with global scope, username `tomcat8`, empty password and the full private key from `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` to `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`
5. I'v created a jenkins creditals "username / password" with the plain username and passwort of the github account.
6. When I log into the user `tomcat8` and check the github authentication via shell with the command `ssh -T git@github.com` I get the correct output. That means my authentication with the key against github works (right?)

   > tomcat8@ci:~/.ssh$ ssh -T git@github.com
   >   Hi github-username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

Wenn I now setup my jenkins job: `repository URL: https://github.com/repoownername/reponame.git` and use the username/passwort-credential the access is fine. But when I use the ssh-credentials the authentication failes with

> Failed to connect to repository : Command "git -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h https://github.com/repoownername/reponame.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
>   stdout:
>   stderr: remote: Invalid username or password.
>   fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/repoownername/reponame.git'

Further information
When I run a build with the username/password credentials

> git config remote.origin1.url https://github.com/repoownername/reponame.git # timeout=10
>   Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/repoownername/reponame.git
>   using .gitcredentials to set credentials
>   git config --local credential.username github-username # timeout=10
>   git config --local credential.helper store --file=/tmp/tomcat8-tomcat8-tmp/git1018128562913260002.credentials # timeout=10
>   git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/repoownername/reponame.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin1/*
>   git config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10

When I use the SSH credentials I get the the error mentioned above.

So my question is now: **How can I successfully use my SSH-credentials instead of Username/Password**

Some of the tutorials I checked:

- https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/
- https://gist.github.com/misterbrownlee/3708738
- http://fourkitchens.com/blog/article/trigger-jenkins-builds-pushing-github
- https://nicolas.perriault.net/code/2011/setup-jenkins-github-private-repository-ubuntu/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Oh man I'm some kind of stupid.

My error was that I used the wrong URL of my repository! I had used:

`https://github.com/repoownername/reponame.git` which works fine when using the `username/password` credentials.

But for SSH-Acess I had to use

`git@github.com:repoownername/reponame.git`

Comment: Have been struggling with this for 3 hours and using the https link, trying to make SSH key work.